# Initial loading of a program using demand-paged virtual memory

Tags: memory-management, paging

When I execute a program on a system that uses demand-paged virtual memory, is the object file copied into the swap space before starting execution?

I know that, when I try to execute a program, space is reserved in the processes' virtual address space, but the code/data itself isn't brought into MM until referenced, via the paging system. It's my understanding that the paging system typically (i.e besides memory-mapped files) deals with transferring pages/frames to/fro MM and swap space. However, if I just began executing a program, then I only see two possibilities:

1. On the initial page fault for some data, the data is paged in from the object file on disk, somewhat like memory-mapped files. Following that, that particular page/frame will be be written back and forth between swap space/MM as normal
2. The executable file is copied into swap space before execution, so that on the first page fault for a frame, it already resides in swap space

Comment: AFAIK most OS's memory-map the program's instructions from the executable or library; there's no reason to copy them to swap first.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo this is what I was thinking - the extra copying didnt make sense. But then the paging system needs to keep track of frames on disk in both partitions, yes?

Comment: Yea, it has to support multiple partitions (what if you mmap two files from different partitions?)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Good point. However, what if the code needs to be relocated. Does the relocation happen when the code is brought into MM for the first time then?